# Spark Structure Streaming on RockDB is not clearing the disk

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, rocksdb

I have been running spark statefull structured streaming in EMR production, before statestore was running on HDFS backend and accumulating Few GB;s like (2.5 gb) in hdfs directories, Later when I moved to rocksdb backend with 3.2.1, It accumulates close to 45GB in last 10days.

Also I using default rocksDB spark configurations.  Im sure, It was clearing the state after the processing time out, Even now I see only 25MB and 6.5 million records in spark UI in overall.
How can we pruge rocks db statestore beyond some storage limit ?

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of the stateful streaming queries to look at and see the metrics. What kind of stateful streaming is this? An aggregation? A join? Something else? What's the output mode? Any watermark?

Comment: I believe beyond the lookback window , the state should be purged .